# Why do I have a "locale error" running a jython script which was copied from a Mac?

Tags: python, jython

I have a little python framework which is used to configure our "virtual" test systems. Those test systems are running some RH-based Linux; and on each system, there is a specific JVM running.

Now I have this strange problem:

1. My python framework copies a small X.py script to the remote system (using scp)
2. My python framework then uses ssh to trigger our special "jython" wrapper ... to simply load&execute the aforementioned X.py in the context of that remote system/JVM

If the system where my framework is running on ... is some kind of Linux (Ubuntu or RedHat) ... everything just works.

But now I got my first "Mac user" to use my framework. When he is running my framework locally on his Mac, he gets this error output for the remote call to jython:

```
b'Traceback (most recent call last):'
b'  File "xxxjython", line 19, in <module>'
b'    xxxjython.main()'
b'  File "xxxjython.py", line 296, in main'
b"    locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')       # Read env var to initialize locale info"
b'  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/locale.py", line 513, in setlocale'
b'    return _setlocale(category, locale)'
b'locale.Error: unsupported locale setting'
```

We could fix/workaround the issue by running this here

```
echo 'export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8' >>/etc/bashrc
```

on the remote system first. But still I am puzzled - why do I need this export on the remote system; if the only difference (compared to a "working" setup) is the OS of the system, on which my "master framework" is running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I found that this is related to how "locales" work in conjunction with remote system. More information for that can be found [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87745/what-does-lc-all-c-do).

My solution was to set

os.environ["LC_ALL"] = "C"

within my framework. This "overrides" all locale settings; and it flows down from python into my ssh call into the remote jython call.